# Access to the path is denied C# error

Tags: asp.net, file, access-denied

I want my user to be able to hit the submit button and have a string write into a css file.  When I hit the submit button, I am getting the error message:

> Access to the path 'C:/.....' is denied

This happens when running the site from localhost and on my hosting (123reg)

```
protected void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("B00101168.css")) 
   { 
      writer.Write("Word "); 
      writer.WriteLine("word 2"); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Is anyone going to give the poor new user some feedback for their downvotes?

Comment: @user1305075-Can you show how are you trying to write it to the 'CSS'?

Comment: Then you are free to skip answering the question. But don't downvote without giving the user some feedback.

Comment: @CharlieKilian Ok, let me say you some thinks, the vote have the meaning that this question need some thinks to be a real question, is not fully understandable, is not include the real problem but we need to guest it, and you need to say some how to the users that love this kind of questions that they must impove them self , and the rest users that no need to read it. Also when some one improve his question usually the vote turn. So this user must make it more clear, more real and probably also find a real help.

Comment: Thank you 'Charlie Kilian'.  Some of us are new to this sort of stuff and a lot of tutorials out there don't make much sense.

Comment: @dotnetter My code for writing is protected void btnSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("B00101168.css"))
        {
            writer.Write("Word ");
            writer.WriteLine("word 2");
        }
    }

Comment: Much better, Aristos. That is feedback the OP can use to improve the question. To the questioner, try embedding that code in your question, with formatting. See the help next to the question box for instructions on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is, you can't write to a file without setting permissions on the folder. See [this link](http://coppermine-gallery.net/tutorial/permissions/iis.php) for details. Essentially, you must give the Internet Guest Account permission to write to the folder.

But, the bigger problem is, you probably shouldn't be trying to dynamically write a CSS file anyway. At least, not the way you are trying to do it. Can you explain why you are trying to dynamically change a CSS file on your server? If you can explain what you are trying to accomplish, I might have some suggestions on how to do it that work better than what you are trying to do.

UPDATE: You're using WebForms, and you're trying to dynamically generate CSS. So here's one way to do that.

Use a generic page handler -- a file that ends in `.ashx`. You dynamically create the CSS however you're doing it now, but instead of writing it to a file, you output it directly to the browser. Here is some (untested!) code:

In the DynamicStyles.ashx file, there is basically nothing to add from what it automatically generates.

In the DynamicStyles.ashx.cs file:

```
public void ProcessRequest( HttpContext context )
{
    StringBuilder css = new StringBuilder();
    // Use the StringBuilder to generate the CSS 
    // however you are currently doing it.

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    context.Response.Write( css.ToString() );
}
```

Then, in your code that needs the CSS file, include it just like you would any other CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/DynamicStyles.ashx">
```

Comment: The first problem is that is not include the full path !

Comment: aristos, you aren't being constructive so can you please leave this topic thank you.  @charlie kilian the reason why I am trying to write a css file is because I want my users to be able to edit some features of the css like the background-color etc.  I thought I could let them specify the colour and it would be written into a css file

Comment: @user1305075, Aristos has a point, he actually tries to help here. How can you write a file only by name? You need to give a full path. DotNetter made an answer, but is in some way wrong..

Comment: @user1305075 Ok, as you love, I close this topic if you think that - no problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The css file is in the same folder as the editMembers.aspx which wants to write to it

Comment: You should think of a CSS file as static content. It shouldn't be changed by your code. You can change your HTML, but it should rely on static (unchanging) CSS. What are the reasons you have for needing to change your CSS file?

Comment: Because I am trying to create a portfolio website where a user can select a template and then edit some parts of the style. So that each web page has some sort of uniqueness

Comment: @Adrian Iftode: That is not correct. You can write a file with only the filename. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266433/how-does-default-relative-path-resolution-work-in-net

Comment: So what you should do is, create separate CSS files, one for each template. You can set up a different template for each overall look and feel. Then, for specific properties, you can either build a server side page that emits custom CSS, or if it isn't very many properties that are being edited, use the `style="..."` attribute on the elements in the HTML itself. Does this make sense so far?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET WebForms, or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: @bic, you're right, but is relative to the entry assembly, running application and is the wrong way. With ASP .Net we should use Server.MapPath if we want to refer to files inside the website. Even if we use a Virtual Folder

Comment: @charliekilian Thank you for your help.  Based on the help you've given me, would this work correctly for each user that logged in or would they all need their own .ashx file?

Comment: The code in the ashx file should figure out who is logged in, and generate the CSS file for that particular user.

Comment: OK, I'll give that a go and I'll let you know.  Thank you for your help, I really do appreciate it

Comment: I'm still trying to get it to work but I think I'll get there.  Thank you for your help.